# How to send backend fetched data to frontend in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I developed like MVC model in Node.js.

I would like to show `data` by accessing `/`. But now, nothing is showing in `/`.

Are there any wrong points? Or if you have some opinion, please let me know.

In below model, I fetch and get some data, I would like to `pass` this data to my frontend.

```
module.exports={
    getQuiz:function(){
      fetch(API_KEY)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => { const quiz = new Quiz(json)});
    }
};
```

My controller is like this. In this `controller` I use `getQuiz()` function defined in `model`

```
const Quizes = require("../models/Quizes");

module.exports = {
    doGetQuiz:function(req,res,next){
        Quizes.getQuiz().then((result)=>{
            res.json(result);
        });
    }
};
```

My desired goal is to show `data` via `/`.

My router is like this.

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var quizController = require("../controllers/QuizController");

router.get('/',quizController.doGetQuiz);

module.exports = router;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in res and call its methods

```
module.exports={
    getQuiz:function(res){
      fetch(API_KEY)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => { 
          const quiz = new Quiz(json);
          res.json(quiz);
      });
    }
};
```

Your controller

```
const Quizes = require("../models/Quizes");

module.exports = {
    doGetQuiz:function(req,res,next){
        Quizes.getQuiz(res);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

add `return` in your model

```
module.exports={
    getQuiz:function(){
      fetch(API_KEY)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => { const quiz = new Quiz(json); return quiz;});
    }
};
```